# Using Today Extension & Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, today-extension

I don't know if it's a problem with Alamofire or just how the Today extension is made. I try to make a RESTful API request in app extension using the same url as I do in containing app. While the request is successful in the containing app, the request always fails in the extension. Can someone please tell me if it's possible to make RESTful api calls in extensions with Alamofire.

[This is what I found in Apple's developer documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6)

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you have proper ATS settings in the extensions plist?

Comment: Yeah. I configured it same as the container app @hnh